# How much resources does Chkdsk (formatting) use?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, formatting, chkdsk

I just received an RMA'd 4TB Red hard drive replacement. I'm thinking I should run a full format (i.e. fully chkdsking it) to verify the drive and flag any bad sectors, especially since RMAs are typically refurbs.

Knowing that formatting will take many hours, I'm wondering what the systemwide resource usage/effects would be, particularly disk controller bandwidth. If I'm formatting/chkdsking this 4TB drive in the background*, would there be noticeable disk I/O bandwidth constraints? What if the drive was connected through an external enclosure (eSATA, but also wondering about if it was over USB 2.0, just out of what-if curiosity)

*Win7, x58, i7 @ 4.2ghz, 24GB 1600, Intel ICH10R SATA, [5 drives], WD Red 4TB 5400 (RMA'd)

Comment: Over USB 2 it's pretty much a given the port / protocol itself would be the bottleneck, without affecting anything else significantly. (Anecdotally speaking, if I'm copying a movie to the drive I hook up to the TV later, I can still use my wireless mouse...)

Comment: Chkdisk (which is not a format program as it is nondestructive) or any formatting program is a poor substitute for a real disk analysis tool. Use the SMART extended test for that.

Comment: somebody gave an interesting comment to something similar http://superuser.com/questions/202313/how-long-can-i-expect-a-chkntfs-to-run-on-500-gb-drive

Comment: MJZ wrote Running time for chkdsk is typically O(number of files) not O(size of disk). You can venture a worst-case of two seeks/file (directory to file record and back). Figure 5ms/seek that's 10ms/file or 100 files/sec... Note that that is the WORST case. CHKDSK does give an indicator, just not an accurate one as to expected time remaining due to the fact that each pass is highly sensitive to the data placement on the disk and to read that placement and give you an accurate time is pretty much the same time as just doing the check. – MJZ